# Launching application from a SMS message

Tags: iphone, sms

I am new to `iphone` application development.

I have a sample application that needs to be launched from a **SMS message**. I have no idea on how to do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow your application to respond to some url (eg: myapp://launch ) and include the url in the SMS, when the user launches that URL your application will launch.

I'm sure that is not the most straight forward way (since the SMS needs to include your custom URL) but I don't know if it is possible with any arbitrary SMS to launch an arbitrary applciation

do a google on iphone URL scheme and you will find lots of detail on how to implement this

here is an [example](http://inchoo.net/iphone-development/launching-application-via-url-scheme/)

Comment: Can you also please tell me how to make my application respond to an url?

Comment: I am able to make my application respond to an url. When that url is typed in safari, it opens the application. I haven't tested this with SMS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: sure, I will let you know. Im unable to test it, since the device is unavailable. I don't think I can test this feature in simulator(composing a SMS message with the url).

Answer (score 9):

Note that if SMS operates in the same manner as Mail on the iPhone, you'll need to enclose your custom URL in brackets to make it launch the application responding to that scheme.  For example,

```
<yourapp://yoururl>
```

will work, but

```
yourapp://yoururl
```

will not.

Comment: I'm able to open my app when running url in safari. However, the URL in SMS text do not respond to touch. Any ideas?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm using iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

the below appdelegate method tells the full url that used to open your app

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
  //you could parse the url and take action according to that
}
```

The below app delegate method tells which app caused to open your app

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
{
 //you could capture the refered app custom url and open back from your app
return YES;
```

}

with following code snippet you could open the app that opened your app

```
 NSURL *urlObj = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlObj];
```

Pass the custom app url.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. thanks hhafez!

I composed a SMS with url format "myapp://". It didn't work. Then I tried "", then it worked. thanks Brad!

Comment: Good to hear it worked for you, 
you should close the question then ;)

Comment: Could you please share the solution that worked out for you? What exactly string have you entered into sms? I'm using iOS 5.1. and none of the combinations worked out for me.