# iPhone - Open Application from Web Page

Tags: iphone

This sounds odd. In fact, it sounds like a security risk to me. However, I would swear that I have seen web pages that you can click a link on and it opens the app store on the iPhone.

My question is, is it possible to launch any application from through a web page? Can parameters be passed to the application? I do not need technical details. I'm just curious if it is possible.

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. From [Control and configuration of applications through Info.plist - Invoking your iPhone application by URL](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/control-and-configuration-of.html):

> ### Invoking your iPhone application by URL
>
> The CFBundleURLTypes key allows you to specify URL schemes that will cause the iPhone to switch to your application. No, you can't override the schemes for the built-in applications.
>
> If your application is launched using a URL type named scheme, then you can also provide a different startup image "Default-scheme.png" instead of the regular "Default.png".

See [iPhone file extension app association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286615/iphone-file-extension-app-association) for more details.