# Return Back To Application From Browser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ipod-touch

I'm implementing a website call on button touch(in iPhone), so my browser get called in that case and website get opened.

I'm using following code:

```
- (IBAction) websiteButtonTouched{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}
```

Now what I want is to **COME BACK TO MY APPLICATION FROM BROWSER** as In iPhone4.0 and Up the application remain running at background we only have to call that when browser quite...

Thanks In Advance.. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this question:

[iPhone - Open Application from Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299908/iphone-open-application-from-web-page)

As for returning to application where you left off -- if the device supports backgrounding (iOS4+) and your backgrounded app wasn't unloaded (due to memory shortage), the app will return the point you left it.

However, you also have to handle the returning to correct point in app yourself, in the cases that the device doesn't support backgrounding, or app was unloaded due to memory shortage: you can do this by storing information about current state of the app before it exits.

This web page has some very nice flow charts which describe app backgrounding and foregrounding etc.:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging

Comment: But i also want to getBack on same page from where i'v called the browser.. :P

Answer (score 1):

Why not create your own in-app browser? Just put a `UIWebView` inside a navigation controller then put an address bar and a search bar.

Comment: Ammm.. will that web view will exactly function like a browser?? :P

Comment: yes it will. You can even see the content and control how it works.  This is quite a neat way to interact with webservices and the user never has to leave that app.