# Worklight(6.1v) hybrid app - need to open other application from my app

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

This is the case

1) check whether someXXX app is installed in the device

2) if installed open the app.

3) if not, open play store/App store app with someeXXX page.

if there any examples or codebases or links provided would be helpful and appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also take a look at the following accepted answer: [IBM Worklight - How to launch another app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612326/ibm-worklight-how-to-launch-another-app)

Two options are provided within:

- Using URI schemes
- Using a Cordova plug-in in your Worklight application (demo project attached)

Comment: tried the example and also the steps in txt file..I see this error "App failed opening"

Comment: Can you provide Your Xcode project (or a demo of it) to debug?

Comment: I can give you android one if needed as i dont have mac right now.

Answer (score 1):

Check this plugin, looks like it answers all your points: https://github.com/lampaa/org.apache.cordova.startapp

Comment: is this plugin supports only android?

Comment: At the bottom of the page, there is an ios example!!