# Is there any way to launch one application from another application in android and ios using worklight 6.2 or phonegap hybrid applications?

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to launch one application that already installed in my device from another application by some action like clicking on a button. I want to implement this both in android and ios applications as I am developing worklight hybrid application.

I want to know whether this is feasible in hybrid applications using IBM worklight or phonegap.

Let me know if any other information is needed on this.

Comment: If my answer helped you solve this issue, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can implement Cordova plug-in(s) that will do this.

See user documentation on creating Cordova plug-ins in Worklight: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_native_to_hybrid

Here's a Worklight 6.2 demo project (instructions.txt inside), demonstartnig opening external (installed) apps in Android and iOS in different fashions: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5dd5hqvx8aplltc/6.2-OpenExternalAppProject%20.zip

---

Related questions with more ways to do this:

- [IBM Worklight - How to launch another app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612326/ibm-worklight-how-to-launch-another-app)
- [Worklight(6.1v) hybrid app - need to open other application from my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273233/worklight6-1v-hybrid-app-need-to-open-other-application-from-my-app)