# How to Launch/Open any other external app from hybrid app?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am using IBM Worklight Studio 6.1.0.02-20151114-1310.

Followed link [IBM Worklight - How to launch another app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612326/ibm-worklight-how-to-launch-another-app)

Downloaded Worklight 6.1.0 demonstration project which is provided in link. Followed instructions.txt file.

Each time am getting "App failed opening" log. Also tried with different valid package names which are installed in device. For all apps its getting failing.

Comment: Then post a comment and write your exact steps that you've followed. Don't start a new question. That project is working for me in 6.1 with Android.

Comment: Small correction : I am using IBM Worklight Studio 6.1.0.02-20160314-1430. I made my query in answer section in above link. Please do help

Comment: Please make correction in uploaded demonstration project. There is problem with confix.xml . I made and now its working for me.