# Launch an app from a link in an SMS

Tags: iphone, sms

I have a very strange requirement...
I need to launch my app from let's say, a hyperlink that is received in an SMS.
Can this be done somehow?
I mean, the person who receives the SMS simply taps on the link provided in the "special SMS", and that launches the application.
Something like a special link which invokes the app in the device...

I have stumbled into an article that shows how message body can be created and sent programmatically in iOS4 and I think that might help me in the creation of the "special message"
So creation of the message may not be an issue here... :|
It's the invocation part...
Anybody knows what can be done???
Suggestions and sample codes greatly appreciated... :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching application from a SMS message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625232/launching-application-from-a-sms-message)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good news, it is possible and quite simple (really easy in fact)

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20110222053023/http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

**Update** : it seems that the SMS app doesn't auto recognize that address type

Comment: Woah! thanks! looks like its the stuff i need... I'll try it out. Thanks again! :))

Comment: Hey! thankx! this works really great... I was able to do the 'launch an app from another app' thing... But the tragedy of the situation is that I am unable to launch it from the SMS... IF I have used the URL scheme as myApp, then typing "<myApp://something>" in the compose message should automatically detect it and make it clickable right? Well this is where its not working... Please help :(

Comment: @santoni: I read your update... :(( So what do i do to fix it? do i change the address type or something????? Help! And check this out- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625232/launching-application-from-a-sms-message . Someone has been successful in launching app from SMS it seems. I wonder how...

Comment: Maybe Apple changed something or in the thread they didn't really test.. I tested on iPhone 4, I'll test on our 3GS

Comment: @santoni: thanks for your support :) Its a tragedy that it failed in iOS 3.1.2 because that's what I was using too. And you said you tried in iPhone 4..did it work in that???

Comment: It failed on both iPhone 3GS and 4.

Comment: Looks like the SMS App no longer recognizes the URL scheme for the installed Apps. One workaround (uncool though) is to send a mail instead of the sms; containing the URL scheme as a hyperlink text. In the mail application, this becomes clickable and launches the app when the user taps on it.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is get your app to respond to a custom URL sequence, such as myApp://open

Apple has documentation on this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/communicating_with_other_apps_using_custom_urls

if you need more help, please ask.

This will also work with mail and webpages, anywhere you can put a clickable link...

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)) I'll got through the doc.. And I'm sure that as i progress into the creation of this app, i'll be stumbling into a lot of things where i'll be crying out "Help!". Sure, I'll be asking you then ^___^ thanks again!

Comment: "Help!" Well in my app I also need to pass parameters to the app via the url...So any idea what the URL scheme will look like? :P

Comment: Look at the tutorial from my response you can handle myapp://whatyourwant and then when the app is launched you can check the URL and do what you want :)

Comment: Help! I gave the URL Scheme as: simpleApplication and the URL Identifier as : com.company.simpleApplication. I did as told in the tutorial. I tried :
1. "simpleApplication"
2. "<simpleApplication>"
3. "simpleApplication://"
4. "<simpleApplication://>"
5. <simpleApplication>
6. <simpleApplication://>
in the compose message and after all these permutations, still the URL is not being identified and the App is not getting launched!

Please tell me where did i go wrong...i'm desperate :((

HELP!!!

Comment: @DepartamentoB Done :)

Answer (score 2):

All the reply you got from Tom H and F. Santoni are great. If you try it with Safari and it launches your application, but you don't see a clickable link in the Message application, then you just have to kill the Message app and start it again.
Then it will read at the launching what scheme are registered by which application, and then you link simpleApplication:// will be clickable/touchable.

Answer (score 0):

`"<simpleApplication://>"` should work for u...!!!