# How to open a native ios app through sms?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have my own native ios app and registered it for custom URL schemes and it's URL scheme is `myapp://`
for example, and my sms is

```
Welcome

myapp://
```

I need to open this native application by clicking on the link. when i am giving as it is,but it is not recognized as a link. Does anyone have any ideas?

and also i need to pass the message body to the application.the "Welcome" message should be displayed on the application screen when it opens.

Comment: You could send an SMS message with a link like so: `http://app.com/sms?message=MESSAGE`, then have your website redirect to `myapp://...` with the message parameter, if that's allowed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512664/launch-an-app-from-a-link-in-an-sms

Comment: @charlie can u please explain me clearly,i didn't get you

Comment: @Charlie,thank you very much.it worked for me..but can you please tell me how to pass the message content through that link to my application?